# Remove extra char in the string in shell script

Tags: shell

```
line="premon D0000070 0x201 0x40"  # it has 26 chars
echo $line | wc -c # giving out put 27 chars.
```

i want to remove the extra char in the string.. please help?

Answer (score 4):

Actually you don't have an extra char in your string. 
`echo` puts a '\n' at the end of line. If you don't want to echo that char, you can do

```
 echo -n $line | wc -c
```

Comment: @SamitKumarPatra if you're pleased with this answer, you can mark this as an answer to your question.

Comment: file1.txt 
premon D0000070 0x201 0x40

script.sh

CommandFileName=$1
while read line 

./script.sh file1.txt  // will it read newline char as well?

Comment: @SamitKumarPatra I don't understand your new question. Who are file1.txt,script.sh? BTW: If you have another question, you should make another topic, because this site works with one question/topic.

Comment: yes sure, thes script came as a comment , so it is not understood.. i will put in another question.